# how to show checkout step number using knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, magento2, checkout

i need to show steps number in magento 2 checkout, 1 - shipping , 2- review & payment , the steps title is showing but the number no, and i'm not good at knockout js

```
    <a data-bind="click: $parent.navigateTo, css: item.isVisible() ? ' 
    step-active' : ($parent.isProcessed(item) ? '_complete' : '')" 
    href="" class="wizard-step-item btn-default">1</a>
```

Comment: Add a `text`  binding: https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html

Comment: Do check the syntax of css-biniding before you fix anything else. https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html